# C programming questions (newbie)

Tags: c

I read Kernighan & Ritchie C programming book now and have a few questions about 'getchar' and 'putchar'.

1. The question is below the code example:

   ```c
   #include <stdio.h>
   int main(void) {
       int c;
       c = getchar();
       while(c != EOF) {
           putchar(c);
           c = getchar();
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```

When I run this code in the terminal and enter a symbol (for example 'i') and than press Enter it prints entered symbol:

i // entered symbol
i // printed symbol

After that it invites me to enter another symbol. If I enter another symbol the procedure repeats. If I press Ctrl-D (EOF) instead of entering another symbol, the program terminates. The first question is why when I run this code and after entering a symbol ('i') and I don't press Enter but I press Ctrl-D, it prints entered symbol and prints it in that way:

ii // the first symbol is entered, the second is printed after Ctrl-D

So to terminate the program I need to press Ctrl-D again.

2. Why in the code above I can enter a word and it prints a word and in code below it prints only one symbol even if I entered a word? The code:

   ```c
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(void) {
       int c;

       printf("Enter a character:\n");
       c = getchar();
       printf("Entered character is:\n");
       putchar(c);
       printf("\n");

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Newlines? This would probably fit in better on Stack Overflow

Comment: Today I have asked another question on Stack Overflow and it says  I can't ask again for some time.

Comment: I agree, StackOverflow would have been a better place. However, the Ask Ubuntu FAQ clearly covers questions about development under Ubuntu. Since he's here we can assume he's using Ubuntu to develop even though it is a fairly generic question.

Comment: Vitaly, You asked your first question on Stack Overflow and you got an answer.  Now you want more information on the same question and Stack Overflow is asking you to go slowly, so you post your original question with the modification here, effectively doubling your question rate, but decreasing the overall throughput of the system as a whole.
You *can*"ask development questions here, but **they have to be directly related to development under Ubuntu**  This is generic K&R C, not specific to Ubuntu, therefore referring you to StackExchange Overflow.

Comment: That being said: getchar() does what it's supposed to do: it gets one (1) *character*, so to read a *string*, you need to loop it to read more then one character!  :-)

Comment: @Fabby I don't think I asked on Stack Overflow the same question. I tried to ask, but it said I can't do it for some time. So I started searching another platform to ask and ended up here. I saw here were questions similar to mine so I made a post. I know that it doesn't related to development under Ubuntu, but I had no idea it's a big problem. Sorry. Next time I'll be more cautious.

Comment: @Fabby and thanks for the answer about getchar().

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I found a similar question and good set of answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-press-enter-with-any-getchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule for input in C, it usually works in lines -- that is, it is buffered. That means that anything you type is not actually sent to the program until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed. So, for the first program, it is simply waiting (also called "blocking") at the `getchar()` request until a line of data comes in. Therefore, it doesn't actually see anything that's typed until the whole line is sent.

The line is sent in the form of "This is a line[EOF]" (where [EOF] is a literal EOF character as defined by the C runtime). The loop in the first program works somewhat like a do/while construct by simply grabbing characters one at a time from the buffer and printing them until the end. As you know, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is a shell synonym for EOF. In the first program, when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> it causes the cursor to move to the beginning of the next line (notice how there is no "\n" in that program, the "\n" is done by the user pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the input line). This is why when you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> that a line break does not occur since it is not the program itself producing the line break but the user pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key that produces this line break.

The second program is much the same, however there is no loop for the `getchar()` call. This means that `getchar()` is called only once. This fetches the first character from the input buffer, prints that character followed by a new line and then exits. Since there is no loop to tell it to do `getchar()` more than once, this is why you're only seeing a single character and not the entire line.

For clarity, remember that input is buffered. So, in the second program you grab a single character from the beginning of the input buffer. However, the rest of those characters will remain there until use use another call to retrieve them. A common mistake when beginning C/C++ programming is forgetting to empty the buffer when you're done with it. Otherwise, that data will remain there.

I remember when I first started programming C++ (my first language) I was confounded that I would use code somewhat like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Enter a sentence: ";
  std::string the_sentence;
  std::cin >> the_sentence;
  std::cout << "\nYou entered: " << the_sentence << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Enter another sentence: ";
  std::cin >> the_sentence;
  std::cout << "\nYou entered: " << the_sentence << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

And I would get an example program run somewhat like:

```
Enter a sentence: Hi my name is Bob!
You entered: Hi
Enter a sentence: (the program would seemingly skip this input block)
You entered: my
```

This is because the std::cin call would only read up until the first space, leaving the rest of the input on the buffer. Come the next std::cin call, it pulled the first thing that was left in the buffer causing it to completely skip the actual input phase as it already had stuff to read still in the buffer.

In order to flush the buffer in C, you could use something like

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

which is simply a one-liner while loop that essentially does the same thing as the loop from the first program, but it simply discards the input

If I answered your question adequately, be sure to select my answer as the best answer. If not, leave me a comment and I'll try to expand my answer further.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think I understand but should think about it a little bit more to be sure. I don't know why these nuances aren't explained in the book. I think it's really important for understanding.

Comment: For me, the best way to learn these things was to simply play with them. Just write a few programs, and experiment! My guess as to why it's never explained is because it may not actually be standardized behavior. I found it was common between Windows and Linux, but I'm not sure about other operating systems like DOS, Solaris, etc. which may act differently. You'll find that a lot of stuff in C/C++ is platform-dependent such as the representation of an EOF character (which I was going to include in my answer but there is no one real answer).

Comment: For the record, when I started C++ I used a lot of C libraries. I wanted a way to be able to read a character as it was typed and found getch(). getch(), however, is not a standardized call. It was originally a part of Borland and may or may not be supported by certain compilers since it's non-standard. Many C libraries include it since Borland was widely used, but it's not a requirement of the C standard and therefore not everybody supports it.

Comment: @Githlar Do you remember TurboC?  What an awful compiler that was! I once wrote a sort of "Hello world" application and then disassembled it and looked at the assembler code! Terrible code that was! >:)

Comment: Haha! No, I never used TurboC++. I started programming around 2001-2002 and was using the Bloodshed Dev-C++ compiler that came recommended by the book I was reading. It was MinGW/G++.